# Python: Deployment on Google App Engine Is Slow

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

When I deploy my project, often it's very fast (a minute or two), but other times it takes forever (ten minutes or more).

Below is a log output when it's takes forever (notice the timestamps). It seems stuck in the "Compilation" phase. Is this a bug with App Engine? Anything I can do to speed it up?

```
10:23 PM Cloning 1436 static files.
10:23 PM Cloning 5055 application files.
10:24 PM Cloned 2000 files.
10:24 PM Cloned 4000 files.
10:24 PM Uploading 1 files and blobs.
10:24 PM Uploaded 1 files and blobs.
10:24 PM Compilation starting.
10:25 PM Compilation: 1461 files left.
10:25 PM Compilation: 1411 files left.
10:26 PM Compilation: 1361 files left.
10:26 PM Compilation: 1311 files left.
10:26 PM Compilation: 1270 files left.
10:26 PM Compilation: 1220 files left.
10:26 PM Compilation: 1172 files left.
10:26 PM Compilation: 1137 files left.
10:27 PM Compilation: 1087 files left.
2015-06-16 22:28:12,619 WARNING util.py:126 new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (6 given)
2015-06-16 22:29:13,371 WARNING util.py:126 new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (6 given)
2015-06-16 22:29:13,371 WARNING util.py:126 new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (6 given)
10:29 PM Compilation: 1046 files left.
10:30 PM Compilation: 996 files left.
10:30 PM Compilation: 946 files left.
10:31 PM Compilation: 896 files left.
10:31 PM Compilation: 846 files left.
10:31 PM Compilation: 803 files left.
2015-06-16 22:32:11,894 WARNING util.py:126 new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (6 given)
10:32 PM Compilation: 753 files left.
10:33 PM Compilation: 703 files left.
10:33 PM Compilation: 659 files left.
10:33 PM Compilation: 609 files left.
10:34 PM Compilation: 573 files left.
10:34 PM Compilation: 523 files left.
10:34 PM Compilation: 489 files left.
10:34 PM Compilation: 453 files left.
10:35 PM Compilation: 422 files left.
```

Comment: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15019

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the App Engine team is performing an upgrade to the system, many times it is a version change.

It will speed up again once the migration is completed, the great thing about App Engine is you don't have to worry about it and you app will continue to work throughout the migration :)